# Regex expression for start and end with characters in between numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I have requirement in javascript where the starting and ending of a word is a Character with in between numbers.
e.g. S652354536667U

I tried with pattern

```
(/[A-Z]\d+[A-Z]$/).test(S652354536667U) // returns true ok
(/[A-Z]\d+[A-Z]$/).test(S65235Y4536667U) // returns true needed false
```

but it is allowing characters in between like S65235Y4536667U is being accepted.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You left **caret** in the beginning.

```js
["S652354536667U", "S65235Y4536667U"].forEach(item => {
    console.log(/^[A-Z]\d+[A-Z]$/.test(item))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a caret at the start of the regex, to indicate the first letter is at the start of the string, i.e.:

```
^[A-Z]\d+[A-Z]$
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `^`. It should be:

```
^[A-Z]\d*[A-Z]$
```

You can use this site to quickly test your regex: https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to put ^ at the start and $ at the end in the reg ex. Otherwise if the pattern match anywhere else in the input, it will return true

```
(/^[A-Z]\d+[A-Z]$/).test(S652354536667U) // returns true 
(/^[A-Z]\d+[A-Z]$/).test(S65235Y4536667U) // returns true
```

Check the below image. It is without specifying the start position. So, from the character 'Y' matching the reg ex

[image]

Below is with the starting position

[image]